# Правильный редирект laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, framework

Всем привет! Пишу сейчас опрос в котором представим 5 вопросов, ссылка генерируется контроллером(стягиваются вопросы по выбранному опросу из БД). Ссылка в адресной строке генерируется вот в таком виде https://somepolls.com/1/1 - где первая цифра номер опроса, вторая цифра номер вопроса.

Представим что пользователь начал отвечать на вопросы => ответил на первый вопрос, ответил на второй вопрос, затем на третий(ссылка в данный момент https://somepolls.com/1/3) и пользователь или случайно или специально нажал в браузере кнопку назад. Мне же нужно сделать так чтоб его с предыдущего вопроса отправило на тот вопрос с которого он вернулся назад, т.е с . https://somepolls.com/1/2 , должно отправить обратно на https://somepolls.com/1/3.

Было принято решение записывать в сессию вопросы на которые пользователь отвечал, проверяем на наличие ответа в сессии, если ответ есть вернуть пользователя обратно(для этого я использую значение из сессии session()->get('_previous')['url']), но если пользователь еще раз нажмет на стрелку назад, его уже отправит не на https://somepolls.com/1/2, а на https://somepolls.com/1/1 и обратно отправит на https://somepolls.com/1/3, соответственно если еще раз пользователь нажмет назад то пропускается и https://somepolls.com/1/2 и https://somepolls.com/1/1 и пользователя отправляет на главную страницу. Как решить вопрос пропуска стриниц на которых пользователь уже пытался попадать зарание??

Помогите плиз уже 3 дня не могу решить эту проблема, я уже и return back() использовал и Url::previous(), вроде как редиректит отрабатывает првильно, но вылазит вот такая проблема.

Заранее спасибо=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно хранить в сессии текущий вопрос на который нужно ответить, то есть если дошел до 3, то будет значение 3, если переходит на вопрос где меньше или больше текущего вопроса(3), то редиректит на текущий вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Думаю в вашем случае можно сделать так:

```
$opros = 1;
$vopros = 2; //<= сюда соотв-но пишете логику вычисления предыдущего вопроса
$route = $opros . '/' . $vopros;
return redirect($route)
```

Правильный редирект https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redirects